# How can I get access to the name of a deleted app in itunesconnect (app store)?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I had to delete my app in itunesconnect (incorrect Bundle ID Suffix) and now it says the name is already being used, how can I get it back?

The (?) beside the App Name says: "The name of your app as it will appear on the App Store."

So now I've got a game called X and all my art says X... but now I can't actually add a game to the store called X!?!

I guess maybe I'll have to call it "X - Insanely Insane!"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a new app with the same app name if you change the default language. I just had the same issue as you and I changed default language from English to UK English and everything went smoothly.

Full details here: http://hesh.am/2012/01/recovering-a-deleted-app-name-in-itunes-connect/

Answer (score 3):

Apple gets the best answer:

Hello Josh,

Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Support regarding iTunes Connect.

Please know that it is not possible to reuse a SKU or App Name in the same account again and you will not be able to restore your app once deleted.